# Loading tile sheet in Libgdx

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx, tile

I'm using Libgdx and I'm still kind of a noob with it (not programming, just Libgdx). I have one of those large png tile sheets, and I also have the individual tiles. What I'd like to do is make it easy on myself how I load these things. Right now, I'm loading them individually by passing a filename like this:

```
final String[] fileNames =
        { "data/brick_dark1.png", "data/dngn_open_door.png",
         "data/cobble_blood1.png", "data/misc_box.png", "data/brick_dark6.png",
         "data/stone_stairs_down.png", "data/stone_stairs_up.png",
         "data/dngn_unseen.png", "data/dirt1.png", "data/dragon1.png", };

for (String s : fileNames)
        {
            texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(s));
            texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

            // TextureRegion region =
            // new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);

            sprite = new Sprite(texture);
            thingRepo.add(sprite);
        }
```

This works just fine, but it also means that my fileNames array has to have every asset known to man explicitly specified. So, can I do it one of these ways, or am I doing it right already?

1. Generically load all assets in my assets folder without knowing the file name. I suppose that's hard because I have to have a way to easily map them as I load (say, in a Map).
2. Load the large tile sheet, index it and store it in a map. Same problem as number 1.
3. Do it the right way, which someone will hopefully now explain to me.

Bonus brownie points for other improvement ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Atlas` with `TexturePacker2`. You should economize number of used textures for tile rendering (best choose is only one big texure), because `SpriteBatch` caches render calls for the same texture.

Place your tiles in some forlder (e.g. `tiles/tile-1.png`, `tiles/tile-2.png`), and convert them all into altas via batch script:

```
java -cp /path-to-the/gdx.jar;/path-to-the/gdx-tools.jar com.badlogic.gdx.tools.imagepacker.TexturePacker2 %source_folder%/tiles %destination_folder%/tiles
```

`TexturePacker2` pack all textures that will be found into `Atlas`. Now you could load it:

```
TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("tiles/yourAtlas.atlas"), false);
```

Now you could get loaded tiles by calling `atlas.getRegions()`, or, use `Skin` to hold them:

```
skin.addRegions(atlas);
```

Now you can simply get the tile (`TextureRegion`, not `Texture`) by calling:

```
skin.getRegion("tile-1")
```

I hope this helps you.